# i want to insert data in a new model after calling is through a post method , how do in do that when a i call it through the template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

## models.py

```
from django.db import models


class booking(models.Model):

    fname=models.CharField( max_length=50)
    lname=models.CharField( max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pin=models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
        return self.fname

class approved(models.Model):

    fname=models.CharField( max_length=50)
    lname=models.CharField( max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pin=models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
        return self.fname
```

## views.py

```
def adminp(request):
if 'form_rejected' in request.POST and request.method=="POST":
    print("Went into reject")
    p=booking.objects.filter(id=request.POST.get('object_id','')).delete()
    print(p)
elif 'form_approved' in request.POST and request.method=="POST":
    print("went in approve")
    fname= booking.objects.filter(fname=request.POST.get('object_fname','')).values_list('fname')
    lname= booking.objects.filter(lname=request.POST.get('object_lname','')).values_list('lname')
    email= booking.objects.filter(email=request.POST.get('object_email','')).values_list('email')
    city= booking.objects.filter(city=request.POST.get('object_city','')).values_list('city')
    state= booking.objects.filter(state=request.POST.get('object_state','')).values_list('state')
    pin= booking.objects.filter(pin=request.POST.get('object_pin','')).values_list('pin')
    app= approved(fname=fname,lname=lname,email=email,city=city,state=state,pin=pin)
    app.save()
    print(fname,pin)
x=booking.objects.all()
params={'pro': x}
return render(request,'dbms/adminpanel.html',params)
```

## template

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col"><p>Firstname: {{i.fname}}</p></div>
  <div class="col"><p>Lastname: {{i.lname}}</p></div>
  <div class="col"><p>Email: {{i.email}}</p></div>
  <div class="col"><p>City: {{i.city}}</p></div>
  <div class="col"><p>Pin: {{i.pin}}</p></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="object_fname" value="{{ i.fname }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="object_lname" value="{{ i.lname }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="object_email" value="{{ i.email }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="object_city" value="{{ i.city }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="object_state" value="{{ i.state }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="object_pin" value="{{ i.pin }}">
  <input class="btn btn-success mx-2" name="form_approved" type="submit" value="Approve">
  <input type="hidden" name="object_id" value="{{ i.id }}">
  <input class="btn btn-danger mx-2" name="form_rejected" type="submit" value="Reject">  <!--Added attribute name="form_rejected"-->
```

OUTPUT after printing output of fname and pin:

```
went in approve
<QuerySet [('snaTYE',)]> <QuerySet [(939393,)]>
```

when I print fname just to check it gives me a queryset which can't be inserted, so how do either insert the following in approved database or how do get only value in the queryset.

Comment: Do you understand what `booking.objects.filter(...)` is doing?

Comment: I think you'd benefit a lot having a look into the [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) documentation

Comment: I will have go through by forms and then comeback!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the value of the hidden field `object_id` to get the `booking` instance. You don't need the other hidden fields. As you discovered, `booking.objects.filter()` gives you a queryset. Use `booking.objects.get()` to get a single instance. Not that this raises an exception if no database entry matching your query exists. Then use the values from the `booking` instance to create the `approved` instance.

```
try:
    booking_obj = booking.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('object_id')
    approved_obj = approved.objects.create(
        fname=booking_obj.fname,
        lname=booking_obj.lname,
        email=booking_obj.email,city=booking_obj.
        city,
        state=booking_obj.state,
        pin=booking_obj.pin
    )
except booking.DoesNotExist:
    # handle error somehow
```

Two remarks:

- check out the documentation on form handling it can make live much easier.
- it is a common convention to capitalize model names (like all class names), e.g. `class Booking`. I'd suggest you stick to this convention, unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: It worked !!! I am a newbie so to django so i don't have much idea about conventions , so thank you for pointing me out there, i will follow the same now onwards!!